# Can't get last day of June with PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

Comment is the output I'm seeing. Help!

```
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("2012-07-31 -1 month")); //2012-07-31
echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("2012-07-31 -2 month")); //2012-05-31
```

July has 31 days, so it can't be processing it as August 1, right? Even if it were, the second line should work. Right?!

Thanks!

Comment: You might have daylight savings time throwing an error in the code - or it could be the fact that this year is a leap year - there could be some imperfect calculations in one of the PHP functions.

Comment: See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) .. Note:

Using this function for mathematical operations is not advisable. It is better to use DateTime::add() and DateTime::sub() in PHP 5.3 and later, or DateTime::modify() in PHP 5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is, "7-31" minus one month comes out as "6-31", which translates to "7-1", which - asking for the last day of the month - comes out as "7-31".

When you want to do month math, it's almost always, if not always, better to build the time using mktime.

```
$month = 7;
echo date("Y-m-t", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month - 1, 1, 2012)); //2012-06-30
```

Note that when doing month math in mktime, always give '1' as the day. Or really anything as long as it's 28 or lower.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, that makes sense. I'll probably switch to that then, but for the time being it should make sense to do: `echo date("Y-m-t", strtotime("2012-07-31 -1 month -15 days"));`. I can't think of an instance that'll fail. But, then again, I also had to post this question ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
$month  = date('m') ;
$day    = date('d') ;
$year   = date('Y') ;
// ----
$current    = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month , $day, $year);
$yesterday  = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month , $day-1, $year);
$tomorrow   = mktime( 0, 0, 0, $month , $day+1, $year);
// ----
echo '<pre>Current Day: '.date('Y-m-d', $current).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>Day Before: '.date('Y-m-d', $yesterday).'</pre>';
echo '<pre>Day After: '.date('Y-m-d', $tomorrow).'</pre>';
```

If you're looking for the last day of July:

```
$july = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 8, 1-1, 2012);
// Last Day of July: 2012-07-31
echo '<pre>Last Day of July: '.date('Y-m-d', $july).'</pre>';
```

Using mktime, just enter the first day of August and subtract one day.

Comment: This completely fails to answer OP's question. Clearly OP is trying to subtract months from the date. The issue is when subtracting from a month with 31 days to get to a month with 30 or fewer days.

Comment: @Matt The OP's problem was getting the last day of June (as stated in their subject).  They where trying to do it by subtracting months.  My answer showed a way of doing so by subtracting one day from the 1st of any given month to accurately get the last day of that month.  If the real question is "why isn't my method working", then yes, I didn't understand the question ask.  A clarification could have been asked so I could have updated my answer.  But I disagree that my answer failed to answer, at least part, of the OP's question.